# Oracle SQL - results from a subquery range

Tags: sql, subquery

I will probably figure this out across the weekend, hard to focus late on a Friday...

Query 1 below returns a trip, with an arrive and depart value at a given location.

Query 2 below returns a trip, with an arrive and depart value at a 2nd location.

These 2 queries are straightforward.

I want to return **only** the results in query 2,when the query 2 depart times are exactly between **any** of query 1's arrive and depart times.

In essence, this will give me any instance of a trip departing 'BER2' before a trip already at 'BER3' has departed.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT     RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TRIP_NAME, RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.ARRIVAL_TIME, RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.DEPARTURE_TIME
FROM         RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS INNER JOIN
                      RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES ON RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TME_ID = RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.TME_ID AND 
                      RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID = RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.THR_ID INNER JOIN
                      RTDEV.TNODED ON RTDEV.TNODED.NID = RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.CURRENT_NODE
WHERE     (RTDEV.TNODED.STRSHORTNAME = 'BER3') AND (RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.TME_ID = 9860)
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT     TRIP_HEADERS_1.TRIP_NAME, TRIP_BODIES_1.ARRIVAL_TIME, TRIP_BODIES_1.DEPARTURE_TIME
FROM         RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS TRIP_HEADERS_1 INNER JOIN
                      RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES TRIP_BODIES_1 ON TRIP_HEADERS_1.TME_ID = TRIP_BODIES_1.TME_ID AND 
                      TRIP_HEADERS_1.THR_ID = TRIP_BODIES_1.THR_ID INNER JOIN
                      RTDEV.TNODED TNODED_1 ON TNODED_1.NID = TRIP_BODIES_1.CURRENT_NODE
WHERE     (TNODED_1.STRSHORTNAME = 'BER2') AND (TRIP_BODIES_1.TME_ID = 9860)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple - you can put the `query2` inside an inline view (a view in the `FROM` clause) like this:

```
SELECT     TRIP_HEADERS_1.TRIP_NAME, TRIP_BODIES_1.ARRIVAL_TIME, TRIP_BODIES_1.DEPARTURE_TIME
FROM         RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS TRIP_HEADERS_1 INNER JOIN
                      RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES TRIP_BODIES_1 ON TRIP_HEADERS_1.TME_ID = TRIP_BODIES_1.TME_ID AND 
                      TRIP_HEADERS_1.THR_ID = TRIP_BODIES_1.THR_ID INNER JOIN
                      RTDEV.TNODED TNODED_1 ON TNODED_1.NID = TRIP_BODIES_1.CURRENT_NODE
-- PUT YOUR QUERY 2 HERE --
JOIN (SELECT     RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TRIP_NAME, RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.ARRIVAL_TIME, RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.DEPARTURE_TIME
        FROM         RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS INNER JOIN
                              RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES ON RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TME_ID = RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.TME_ID AND 
                              RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID = RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.THR_ID INNER JOIN
                              RTDEV.TNODED ON RTDEV.TNODED.NID = RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.CURRENT_NODE
        WHERE     (RTDEV.TNODED.STRSHORTNAME = 'BER3') AND (RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.TME_ID = 9860)) query2
-- AND PUT A JOIN CONDITION --
        ON TRIP_BODIES_1.DEPARTURE_TIME BETWEEN query2.ARRIVAL_TIME AND query2.DEPARTURE_TIME
WHERE     (TNODED_1.STRSHORTNAME = 'BER2') AND (TRIP_BODIES_1.TME_ID = 9860)
```